# How to rebind the other ui select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-select

I'm using [angular ui-select](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/). I had two ui-selects, the first ui-select's selection will returns a lists of items that parse into second ui-select. Currently, my first ui-select is selected and the second ui-select shows error.

**HTML**

```
ui-select(ng-model='location.update_country', theme='select2', style='min-width: 300px;', title='Choose a country', on-select="SelectCountry()")
  ui-select-match(placeholder='Select country') {{$select.selected.name}}
  ui-select-choices(repeat='c in countries_list | filter: $select.search')
  div(ng-bind-html='c.name | highlight: $select.search')

ui-select(ng-model='location.update_state', theme='select2', style='min-width: 300px;', title='Choose a state')
  ui-select-match(placeholder='Select state') {{$select.selected.name}}
  ui-select-choices(repeat='c in states_list | filter: $select.search')
  div(ng-bind-html='c.name | highlight: $select.search')
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.SelectCountry = function(){
   Service.GetStatesByCountry($scope.location.update_country.id, function(states){
      $scope.states_list = states; // states variable show correct lists of state
   });
}
```

**console error**

> angular.min.js:118 Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22returnCode%22%3A…00-00-00%2000%3A00%3A00%22%2C%22country_name%22%3A%22Indonesia%22%7D%5D%7D

Comment: How does your  `states_list` looks like ? Array or object.

Comment: @PrabodhM `[{"id":1,"name":"London","country_id":1,"created_at":"2017-06-30T07:05:53.000Z","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","country_name":"UK"},{"id":2,"name":"California","country_id":2,"created_at":"2017-06-30T07:05:57.000Z","updated_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","country_name":"US"}]` what matter are the id and name..